# Make tkinter buttons for every item in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to make some buttons, with a list of items I get back from a database, that all call a function passing in the list item. Something like this code but that works. The problem with this code is that all of the buttons call the function with `'item3'`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def func(name):
    print name
mylist = ['item1','item2','item3']
for item in mylist:
    button = Button(root,text=item,command=lambda:func(item))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is indention correct in your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. You need to indent the following line one level:

   ```
   button.pack()
   ```

   Currently, you only have the `pack` method being called on the last button.  Making this change will cause it to be called for each button.
2. All of the buttons are sending `'item3'` to `func` because that is the current value of `item`.  It is important to remember that the expression enclosed by a lambda function is evaluated at *run-time*, not compile-time.

   However, it is also important to remember that both a function's parameters as well as their default values (if any) are evaluated at *compile-time*, not run-time.

   This means that you can fix the problem by giving the lambda a parameter whose default value is set to `item`.  Doing so will "capture" the value of `item` for each iteration of the for-loop.

Below is a version of your script that addresses these issues:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def func(name):
    print name
mylist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
for item in mylist:
    button = Button(root, text=item, command=lambda x=item: func(x))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def func(name):
    print name
mylist = ['item1','item2','item3']
for item in mylist:
    button = Button(root,text=item,command=functools.partial(func,item))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The same logic, but this is an example of creating a calculator. Only display, no calculations. Here I used grid() instead of pack().

```
import tkinter

main_window = tkinter.Tk()
main_window.title("Calculator")
main_window.geometry('500x500+550+200')
main_window['padx'] = 8

main_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_window.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
main_window.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
main_window.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
main_window.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)

main_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
main_window.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)

title_label = tkinter.Label(main_window, text="Calculator")
title_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=6)

number_entry = tkinter.Entry(main_window)
number_entry.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='nwes')

button_list = [('C', 'E'),
               ('7', '8', '9', '+'),
               ('4', '5', '6', '-'),
               ('1', '2', '3', '*'),
               ('0', '=', '/')]

for outer_num, outer_val in enumerate(button_list):

    for inner_num, inner_val in enumerate(outer_val):
        x = 1
        y = inner_num
        if inner_val == "=":
            x = 2
        if inner_val == "/":
            y += 1
        tkinter.Button(main_window, text=inner_val).grid(row=outer_num + 2, column=y, columnspan=x,
                                                         sticky='news')

main_window.mainloop()
```