# How can I create buttons for every item in a list using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am working on a python app about houseplants and I'm using tkinter. I have a list of plants that all have a specific attribute (in this case, it's the type of plant "foliage") that is called from a database using sqlite. I want to use a for loop to create a button for each item in the list and have each button on a different row and have the text for each button be a different item. I want to use a for loop so as I add plants to the database (and therefor list), I won't have to change my code every time.

```
foliage_list = []
c.execute("SELECT name FROM plants WHERE type_of_plant = 'foliage'")
foliage_result = c.fetchall()
foliage_list.append(foliage_result)
foliage_num = len(foliage_list)

for item in foliage_list:
    for i in range(foliage_num):
        tk.Button(self, text=item)
        tk.Button[i].grid(row=i+1, column=0, padx=30, pady=30)
```

Here I have created the list and then attempted to use a for loop to create a button for each item in the list. I know this is wrong (it doesn't work) but I cannot figure out how to make it work. How can I do this?

Edit:
I have changed my code to this:

```
for item in foliage_list:
    for i in range(foliage_num):
        tk.Button(self, text=item).grid(row=i+1, column=0, padx=30, pady=30)
```

I seems to now create a button for every item in the list in every row for how many rows there are items. I think this has something to do with using a nested for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Also, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/7432

Comment: I just found this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738149/make-tkinter-buttons-for-every-item-in-a-list 
which answers most of my question but I want to use .grid instead of .pack

Comment: Also I get this error: "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" which is what I mean by doesnt work.

Comment: I don't know how to make it so every button is on a different row

Comment: That error is because `tk.Button` is a type (class), and you're trying to do `tk.Button[i]`. That's a bit like doing `int[i]` or `str[i]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
tk.Button(self, text=item)
tk.Button[i].grid(row=i+1, column=0, padx=30, pady=30)
```

Use:

```
tk.Button(self, text=item).grid(row=i+1, column=0, padx=30, pady=30)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved one problem though another has seemed to appear!

Comment: Probably this is what you want: for i, item in enumerate(foliage_list):  tk.Button..., do not use two for loops, one with enumerate is enough.